# Finding a particular token

Tags: compiler-construction, lex

Well I am using lex for finding the tokens. I want to get the Identifier token's value that comes after the token class, how do i do it.

e.g my function should return identifier after the class token. Is there any way to do so?

Lexical tokens genrated by lex   looks as follows : -

```
     LexToken(SEMICOLON,';',15,125)
     LexToken(RETURN,'return',16,127)
     LexToken(SEMICOLON,';',16,134)
     LexToken(RCURLY,'}',17,136)
     LexToken(CLASS,'class',20,140)
     LexToken(IDENTIFIER,'animal',20,146)
```

after giving this stream of token as input to function it should return 'animal' as it the value of token 'Identifier' which follows 'class' token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while True:
    tok = lexer.token()
    if not tok: break      # No more input
    print tok.type, tok.value, tok.line, tok.lexpos 
if flag==1:
   flag=0
   print tok.value       # here u get the value.
if tok.type=='CLASS':
    flag=1
```